# How do I create invite-only access Tradingview script?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I'm currently in need of assistance or at least direction to learn how I can make our current indicator as a published "invite-only" script so that it is locked until a member of ours on our platform pays and then can get their access to the indicator.

What is the process for this and what do I need to do to make sure it's invite-only, along with how to give access to someone that pays for the indicator?

It seems like it should be a simple answer, but I cannot find any info anywhere on this. Please help, we need this done in a few short days :)

I have a Tradingview Premium account and tried republishing our current public indicator but I don't see any options to publish as an invite-only script, unless I need some sort of code put in to make it that way? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your indicator to your chart first and then hit "Publish indicator".

[image]

Then you can set the privacy and visibility settings.

[image]

After it is published, you will have a button on your script's page to manage access.

[image]

I highly recommend you read the [house rules](https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?solution=43000590599) and [vendor requirements](https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?solution=43000549951) before you publish your script.